# simple way to add a custom validation rule to all textboxes

Tags: c#, wpf, validationrules

I'm having problems setting a custom validation rule for all my textboxes in a Page.

I know how to set it for 1 single textbox:

```
<TextBox Margin="79,118,79,121" Name="textBox1" Style="{Binding EmptyTextboxValidator, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="Text" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <validators:StringRangeValidationRule MinimumLength="1" ErrorMessage="Text is te kort" />
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

However, if i need to add this code for every single textbox i'm not sure this is as useful since it would be an awful lot of copy pasting. There must be an easier way right?

if been doing a lot of searching but i couldn't find an example to set it for all textboxes, only examples to set it for 1 single textbox (as shown above)

here's the code for the textbox style:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="EmptyTextboxValidator" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                        <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="3">
                            <AdornedElementPlaceholder Name="MyAdorner" />
                        </Border>
                    </DockPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="ToolTip" 
                        Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, 
                        Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

and the code for the validation rule:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Globalization;

namespace MyValidators
{
    public class StringRangeValidationRule : ValidationRule
    {
        private int _minimumLength = 1;
        private string _errorMessage;

        public int MinimumLength
        {
            get { return _minimumLength; }
            set { _minimumLength = value; }
        }

        public string ErrorMessage
        {
            get { return _errorMessage; }
            set { _errorMessage = value; }
        }

        public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
        {
            ValidationResult result = new ValidationResult(true, null);
            string inputString = (value ?? string.Empty).ToString();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputString) || inputString.Length < MinimumLength)
            {
                result = new ValidationResult(false, this.ErrorMessage);
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

the viewModel:

```
public class Data : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int id = -1;
    private bool updated = true;
    private string text;
    private string name;

    public int ID
    {
        get
        {
            return id;
        }
        set
        {
            id = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ID");
        }
    }

    public bool Updated
    {
        get
        {
            return updated;
        }
        set
        {
            updated = value;
        }
    }

    public string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return text;
        }
        set
        {
            text = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Text");
        }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        updated = true;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Also my knowledge of xaml is limited and this code was part of a test i made to get some more understanding of xaml.

Also might there be a way to just add field to the textbox for example:

```
<TextBox ValidateStringLength="true"/>
```

or even better if i could just give it an integer parameter for the minimum length of the string:

```
<TextBox ValidateStringLength="5"/>
```

Either one of the 2 (setting it as i'm doing but for all textboxes at once) or the example i demonstrated above would be really appreciated.

Comment: Create a custom control that is a text box plus your validation. Then reuse that.

Comment: did you check using IDataErrorInfo for validation? its more mvvm but nice and easy :)

Comment: @blindmeis well almost all wpf applications i make i try implementing the mvvm so that would be nice.
I'll take a look at it.

Comment: @Richard i forgot about the custom controls, that might be a good alternate solution.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is called BindingGroup. Take a look at this code:

```xml
<StackPanel Name="stackPanel1">
  <StackPanel.BindingGroup>
    <BindingGroup NotifyOnValidationError="True">
      <BindingGroup.ValidationRules>
        <src:ValidateDateAndPrice ValidationStep="ConvertedProposedValue" />
      </BindingGroup.ValidationRules>
    </BindingGroup>
  </StackPanel.BindingGroup>

  <HeaderedContentControl Header="Price">
    <TextBox Name="priceField"  Width="150">
      <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="Price" Mode="TwoWay" />
      </TextBox.Text>
    </TextBox>
  </HeaderedContentControl>

  <HeaderedContentControl Header="Date Offer Ends">
    <TextBox Name="dateField" Width="150" >
      <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="OfferExpires" StringFormat="d" />
      </TextBox.Text>
    </TextBox>
  </HeaderedContentControl>

  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Button IsDefault="True" Click="Submit_Click">_Submit</Button>
    <Button IsCancel="True" Click="Cancel_Click">_Cancel</Button>
  </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

All the TextBoxes have ValidateDateAndPrice ValidationRule available.

And you can also control when changes shall be saved.

```cs
private void Submit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (stackPanel1.BindingGroup.CommitEdit())
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Item submitted");
        stackPanel1.BindingGroup.SubmitEdit();
    }
}
```

In this case changes are being submitted when button clicked.

**Edit:**

I will give you an example how to make it work. I used your code to create the example.

```xml
<Window>
    ....
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                            <Border BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="3">
                                <AdornedElementPlaceholder Name="MyAdorner" />
                            </Border>
                        </DockPanel>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip" 
                        Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, 
                        Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Window.BindingGroup>
        <BindingGroup>
            <BindingGroup.ValidationRules>
                <local:StringRangeValidationRule MinimumLength="5" ErrorMessage="Text too long!" />
            </BindingGroup.ValidationRules>
        </BindingGroup>
    </Window.BindingGroup>

    <Grid Margin="10" >
        <TextBox Margin="100, 5, 0, 0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                 Text="{Binding Name}" Validation.ValidationAdornerSiteFor="{Binding ElementName=window}">
        </TextBox>
        <Button Content="Save" Click="Button_Click" Margin="0, 5, 100, 0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

You need to have your templates and styles in window to make it work.

This is the code behind:

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new Data() { Name = "Hello World!" };
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        window.BindingGroup.CommitEdit();
    }
}

public class Data : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int id = -1;
    private bool updated = true;
    private string text;
    private string name;

    public int ID
    {
        get
        {
            return id;
        }
        set
        {
            id = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ID");
        }
    }

    public bool Updated
    {
        get
        {
            return updated;
        }
        set
        {
            updated = value;
        }
    }

    public string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return text;
        }
        set
        {
            text = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Text");
        }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        updated = true;
    }

    #endregion
}

public class StringRangeValidationRule : ValidationRule
{
    private int _minimumLength = 1;
    private string _errorMessage;

    public int MinimumLength
    {
        get { return _minimumLength; }
        set { _minimumLength = value; }
    }

    public string ErrorMessage
    {
        get { return _errorMessage; }
        set { _errorMessage = value; }
    }

    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        BindingGroup group = (BindingGroup)value;
        var item = group.Items[0];
        string inputString = (group.GetValue(item, "Name") ?? string.Empty).ToString();
        if (true || string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputString) || inputString.Length < MinimumLength)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(false, this.ErrorMessage);
        }

        return ValidationResult.ValidResult;
    }
}
```

As you can see I changed the validation rule and I added Validation.ValidationAdornerSiteFor to indicate the TextBox should display error.

You should be able to copy and paste this and it will work.

Comment: so this i could apply application wide, window wide, or page wide? by setting it under .resources? or do i need to place it somewhere else?

Comment: In my case it is the StackPanel that is acting like parent for all the TextBoxes I have. Yes you need to place the BindingGroup in a parent. Window will work too since Window is the parent of all elements. Window is the root. But be careful if you place it in Window because you might end up sharing ValidationRules with TextBoxes you do not want.

Comment: I cannot seem to get it to work with Window, could you give an example for creating it with window instead of stackpanel?

Comment: it's all up in the question you can copy it from there ;)

also, i tried using the code with the stack pannel and it says there is no SubmitEdit() method. (maby because i'm running .net 3.5)

Comment: Give me your data please. The ViewModel is missing post it too.

Comment: though i can use this for all textboxes it does not work on all, since the last textbox declared in the xaml code will be red on error even when that textbox does not contain the error but an other textbox in that window.