# Simplify using of ValidationRules

Tags: c#, wpf, validationrules

I'm working on a C# project in WPF.

In my main windows I have 5 (maybe more late) `TextBox`, each box contains a `float` with a value between 0 and 100.

I've created a validation rule :

```
class RangeValidationRule : ValidationRule
{
    public float MinValue { get; set; }
    public float MaxValue { get; set; }

    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        float intValue;

        string text = String.Format("Must be between {0} and {1}",
                       MinValue, MaxValue);
        if (!float.TryParse(value.ToString(), out intValue))
            return new ValidationResult(false, "Not a float");
        if (intValue < MinValue)
            return new ValidationResult(false, "To small. " + text);
        if (intValue > MaxValue)
            return new ValidationResult(false, "To large. " + text);
        return ValidationResult.ValidResult;
    }
}
```

But I don't know how to simplify the using of it. Actually I use it like this :

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1"
         Style="{StaticResource StyleTextBox}">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="ValueToBind" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <local:RangeValidationRule MinValue="0" MaxValue="100"/>
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

How can I simplify my code ? Can I create a style for this type of TextBox ?

```
<Style x:Key="StyleTextBox0To100" TargetType="TextBox"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource StyleTextBox}">
       <!-- What should I write ? -->
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution you are searching is [BindingGroup](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/21993.wpf-the-myth-of-bindinggroup.aspx)

Previously asked [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20421933/simple-way-to-add-a-custom-validation-rule-to-all-textboxes)

Comment: I've try both way to use BindingGroup (with `Validation.ValidationAdornerSiteFor` and `BindingGroupName`) but it doesn't work for me. I probably missed something but I don't know what